# Cannot add Currency field to Entity after Importing

Tags: entity-framework, dynamics-crm-2011

A custom entity was created in our DEV environment.  It originally had a Currency field, but we decided to remove it and use a Float field for simplicity.  After exporting the solution and importing it into QA for the first time, I can no longer add a Currency field to the entity in QA (and the "leftover" transactioncurrencyid column in DEV did not get migrated to QA).

The main problem is that I cannot remove the transactioncurrencyid column and now my Filtered views are different between DEV and QA which causes our SharePoint BCS process that relies on Entity Framework to fail.

Is there any way to completely remove a currency field without recreating the entity?

Plan B: Is there a way to restore a past copy of the entity (prior to removing the currency) from a backup and merge it into our presently broken version?

Plan C: any other ideas (convert EF to use Stored Procs, etc)?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any other environments that you can you get a back up from them? Pre-production or production that still have the currency field?

Comment: No answer, but a remark (maybe making it worse): float is an approximate number, not really appropriate for something that represents money.

Comment: Is this an unmanaged or managed solution?

Comment: Unmanaged solution and we are not in production yet (only 50% development complete).  We have weekly backups from the beginning so it would be possible, though it seems painful, to restore a previous version and overlay the past 2 weeks worth of changes.  There are a dozen relationships to other custom entities and 100's of lines of early-bound plugin code written against this entity so recreating is definitely a last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSFT approved solution involved manually removing:

1. the ExchangeRate column from the Base table (e.g. alter...drop column exchangerate)
2. the rows referencing the attribute's GUID in the system tables: Attribute, localizedlabel, AttributeIds (e.g. delete from tbl where AttributeId = guid)
3. altering the entity's View to remove the ExchangeRate column (not the Filtered)

Finding the GUID in Step 2 was done by opening the ExchangeRate field in CRM and pressing F11 to extract the AttributeID from the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

Export the entity from Dev into QA again.  CRM will see that a column has been added, and will add it to the entity in QA.

### Edit 1

So this is an unmanaged solution in QA?  You should be able to just add the field to the entity in QA through the Customize Solution interface.

Comment: I tried adding a Currency column back into DEV and exporting to QA, but that attempt failed to import the entity.  I thought I had corrupted the DB, but fortunately removing the column from DEV allowed imports to work again.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: What error are you getting?  Is it a managed solution in QA, and if so, are you using the same publisher?

Comment: I created a new tenant in DEV and imported the same solution there and have reproduced the problem.  The error is:  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #09C9D12

Comment: @ChrisSnyder use the diagnostic tool (http://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com/) to turn on logging and see if you can get a better error, or see what SQL statement it is actually failing on.

Comment: Good call.  I did that and now I can see that it is trying to add another ExchangeRate column, but the column already exists so the SQL unique constraint is failing:  Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'ExchangeRate' in table 'new_myEntity' is specified more than once    --- I have opened an incident with MSFT and the engineer said this is known issue that will be fixed in UR 12, but he has a workaround.  I will post the resolution when I hear back.