# Representing large numbers in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to represent numbers larger than 100,000,000,000 (the maximum of the Decimal data type) in Dynamics CRM 2011.  It seems like the only way to do this is to either use the Currency field or use a text field.  Neither of these options are very appealing.

What is the best way to represent large numbers in Dynamics CRM?

Comment: Driven by a pure curiosity I have to ask what is that atrocity you're keeping a track of. Those are pretty huge numbers, so maybe you could circumference your problem by a change in approach, instead?

Comment: @Konrad Viltersten - it's just money values that are being kept track of, possibly running into the hundreds of billions; but the problem is that a single form may need to display amounts in different fields in different currencies, which is not supported by the inbuilt Currency field.

Comment: Woeful inadequacy of Dynamics. 100bn isn't a large number for some measures in some industries - particularly finance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way is indeed in a currency field or use a text field. You can't increase the maximum value of a decimal field.

However the Float-Field covers until 100,000,000,000 if that's any comfort.

Comment: +1, but 100,000,000,000 for float = 100,000,000,000 for decimal.

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer is to just store in billions (2.15 = 2,150,000,000) - though this won't work if you're adding small numbers to a large number.

Another approach is to add a 'multiplier' field that contains a thousand, million or billion - and multiply the numbers together when required for reporting.

Finally, you could store the number in a string and validate/copy it to/from the number property in RetrieveMultple and PreSave plugins. As long as you're not *saving* the large value in the number field, you can use it to hold transient large values. Use a string as a persistent holder. Hacky, yes - but at least you can then use the value in charts etc.

The 'currency' type is [unstable to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128563/cannot-add-currency-field-to-entity-after-importing)